# Best way to automate tasks in windows

Tags: windows, scripting, automation, applescript, scripting-language

Mac has applescript 'built in' and I've found its pretty nice to work with for automating stuff.

What's the best windows equivalent?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe [PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx) -- but it's really much more powerful than applescript. VBA only exists within specific applications that supply it, such as Excel, not stand-alone.

Comment: Although VBScript via Windows Scripting Host (WSH) is still available, Powershell and .Net will give you a lot easier time in the long run. Seeing as you are looking to just start out, go with Powershell, since it has a future.

Comment: Agreed and here's a starter  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730935.aspx

Answer (score 3):

**VBScript** and **JScript** are standard Windows Script Host languages. See [Microsoft Windows Script Technologies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1et7k7c(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I discovered python when I moved to a PC and was looking for something to do all the kind of stuff I'd usually do with applescript. As someone who learned most of my programming skills using applescript it came pretty easily to me. Best thing is that you can use it on any platform.

BTW applescript has been around [a lot longer than OSX.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applescript)

Answer (score 0):

Powershell is the program to learn if you want to automate stuff in windows.  Microsoft is deprecating vbscript, which is part of Windows Script Host, and pushing Powershell as the modern replacement for vbscript.  For example, Microsoft is creating more and more APIs for Powershell.  On the other hand, vbscript bears a great similarity to vba, which is the default program for automating Word, Excel and Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, there is also the rather dated [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). Originally designed to provide system-wide hotkeys to automate things, it can also be used as a general automation tool.

However, I cannot recommend it. The syntax is horrible and obscure, and that's the reason they are currently doing a complete haulover for version 2.